# Connection with Sybase

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

I am new to Sybase ,I'm developing a web application with sybase and jboss, my app connect with the Sybase database. I have put the jconn4.jar in same directory with war file in deployments directory . My config in standalone.xml like this

```
<connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sybase://<myserver>:<myport>/<mydb></connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver</driver-class> 
                <!--<driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class> -->
                <driver>jconn4.jar</driver>
```

and  when i use com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver got the error message

```
javax.resource.ResourceException: Wrong driver class [class com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver] for this connection URL [jdbc:jtds:sybase://<myhost>:<myport>/<mydb>
```

...

when i use net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver i got the message

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver from [Module "deployment.jconn4.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

I don't know what driver-class suitable for driver class jconn4.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the driver url of the open source jTDS driver, but you are trying to use the Sybase driver. Use the right JDBC url for the Sybase driver: Check the documentation included with the Sybase driver for details (I can't be more specific because the Sybase documentation is usually hard to find online without access to the support portal). Or switch to jTDS, in which case you need to deploy it as a module to JBoss and reference the right driver module in the config.